# A certain doubt in a concept from Syllogism.

Tags: logic

In my textbook "Analytical Reasoning" by M.K. Pandey it mentions about a technique to draw conclusion for syllogism by using some analytical method. It gives a plethora of rules to follow. Though I am used to solving syllogism questions by Venn Diagrams I am not at all well versed with this technique.

It would be great if someone could highlight on the procedure. Like somewhere in my book it says that you need to check for common words in both the subject and the predicate but still I am not able to understand why  the technique doesn't work for questions with both the statements with "All". I feel the book could be a good reference to exactly what I am asking.

Comment: Take heart! Modern logic is much more intuitive. Syllogisms (BARBARA et al) are important only for historical purposes. If you don't need it for a course, you could skip that part or simply skim it without any great loss.

Answer (score 1):

Can you supply some more details? I have no access to the book...I am a bit confused that you bring together Venn-diagrams and syllogism, as far as I know or imagine a 'translation' of one in the other is not without philosophical assumptions...but depending on your goals, this may of course not be of your interest. If you speak and read well german, I can perhaps make a reading suggestion that tries to clarify the relation of several logical theories that emerged in the past. For sure there will also be something in english.
I can't jugde whether it makes sense to study Aristotle's logic 'for itself' (so to speak), you may consider to look here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic
As usual, people will disagree about this, I suppose.
Also, you may want to post this on philosophy stack exchange, maybe you can find more interested/informed readers there.
Hope this helps a bit..